# Como seleccionar una fila de registro de un TreeView y mostrar en un formulario

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy trabajando en la misma aplicación en la que vengo y en esta ocasión tengo un treeview donde estoy visualizando los datos que voy agregando a mi tabla productos desde mi formulario de captura.

No he podido lograr este par de cosas:

1. Que al iniciar la ventana, **el focus de mi treeview quede seleccionando la primera fila de los registros**, sin que tenga que darle clic a la fila para ello.
2. **Que al seleccionar cualquier fila, estos datos se monten en los campos respectivos del formulario de arriba**, para luego proceder a actualizarlos.
3. **Un error en la linea 124** después de agregar campos en la tabla y   limpiar campos.

Les dejo mi código como siempre y les agradezco por favor.

PD: Si la lógica de mi programa no es la adecuada, recibo todas las correcciones y sugerencias que a bien vengan.

Gracias.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

class Product:
    db_name = 'database.db'

    # DEFINIMOS EL CONSTRUCTOR Y TOMAMOS EL PARAMETRO QUE NOS ESTAN PASANDO AL INICIAR LA VENTANA
    def __init__(self, window):

        # CREAR PROPIEDAD U OBJETO PARA ALMACENAR LA VENTANA QUE ESTA RECIBIENDO EL CONSTRUCTOR
        self.win = window
        self.win.title('Aplicacion de Productos')

        self.interfaz_inicial()

        # BOTON AGREGAR PRODUCTO
        ttk.Button(frame, text='AGREGAR PRODUCTO', command=self.add_product).grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2, ipadx=40, pady = 10)

        # LABEL PARA MENSAJES DE SALIDA
        self.message = Label(text = '')
        self.message.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E, padx = 150)

        # TABLA
        frame2 = LabelFrame(self.win, text=' LISTADO DE PRODUCTOS: ')
        frame2.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx = 20, pady = 15)

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(frame2, height = 10, columns=("#1", "#2", "#"))
        self.tree.grid(row = 7, column = 0, columnspan = 2, padx = 20, pady = 10)
        self.tree.heading("#0", text="Nombre", anchor = CENTER)         
        self.tree.heading("#1", text="Precio", anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#2", text="Stock", anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading("#3", text="Seccion", anchor = CENTER)

        # SCROLL VERTICAL TREEVIEW
        scrolvert = Scrollbar(frame2, command = self.tree.yview)
        scrolvert.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.tree.config(yscrollcommand=scrolvert.set)

         # SCROLL HORIZONTAL TREEVIEW
        scrolhoriz = Scrollbar(frame2, command = self.tree.xview, orient='horizontal')
        scrolhoriz.grid(row=12, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="news")
        self.tree.config(xscrollcommand=scrolhoriz.set)

        # BOTONES
        ttk.Button(text='EDIT', command=self.edit_product).grid(row = 13, column = 0, columnspan=2, ipadx = 50, pady = 10)
        ttk.Button(text='DELETE', command=self.del_product).grid(row = 13, column = 1, columnspan=2, ipadx = 50, pady = 10)

        self.get_products()

    # CREACION INTERFAZ GRAFICA
    def interfaz_inicial(self):
        global frame
        # FRAME CONTENEDOR
        frame = LabelFrame(self.win, text=' REGISTRAR UN NUEVO PRODUCTO: ')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 15, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5)

        # INPUT NAME
        Label(frame, text=' Nombre: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        self.name = UpperEntry(frame, width=45)
        self.name.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.name.focus()

        # INPUT PRECIO
        Label(frame, text=' Precio: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        self.price = CurrencyEntry(frame, width=25)
        self.price.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # INPUT STOCK
        Label(frame, text=' Stock: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        self.stock = UpperEntry(frame, width=25)
        self.stock.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # INPUT SECCION
        Label(frame, text=' Seccion: ').grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 20, pady = 5, sticky = W)
        self.section = UpperEntry(frame, width=45)
        self.section.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # BOTON AGREGAR PRODUCTO
        ttk.Button(frame, text='AGREGAR PRODUCTO', command=self.add_product).grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2, ipadx=40, pady = 10)

    # CREAR METODO PARA CONECTAR Y HACER CONSULTAS A LA BASE DE DATOS
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query,parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    # OBTENER DATOS DE LA TABLA product
    def get_products(self):

        #limpiando treeview
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)

        # ejeutando consulta    
        query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)

        # llenando data
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert('',0,text = row[1], values = (row[2], row[3], row[4]))

    # VALIDAR CAMPOS
    def validation(self):
            return len(self.name.get()) != 0  and len(self.price.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.section.get()) != 0
            #return len(self.name.get()) != 0  and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.section.get()) != 0

    # AGREGAR PRODUCTOS
    def add_product(self):
        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO product VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get(), self.stock.get(), self.section.get())
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = 'El Producto {} ha sido agregado!!'.format(self.name.get())
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#d4edda'
            self.message['fg'] ='#116158'

            # LIMPIAR CAMPOS
            self.name.delete(0, END)
            self.price.delete(0, END)
            self.stock.delete(0, END)
            self.section.delete(0, END)
            self.name.focus()

        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Todos los campos son requeridos...'
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#f7d7da'
            self.message['fg'] ='#89312f'
            self.name.focus()

        self.get_products()

    # ELIMINAR PRODUCTOS
    def del_product(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor selecciona un registro'
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#f7d7da'
            self.message['fg'] ='#89312f'
            self.name.focus()
            return
        self.message['text'] = ''    
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM product WHERE name = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (name,))
        self.message['text'] = 'El Producto {} ha sido eliminado!!'.format(name)
        self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
        self.message['bg'] ='#d4edda'
        self.message['fg'] ='#116158'
        self.name.focus()
        self.get_products()

    # EDITAR PRODUCTOS
    def edit_product(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        nuevo = Entry()
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor selecciona un registro'
            self.message['font'] = ('Consolas',11)
            self.message['bg'] ='#f7d7da'
            self.message['fg'] ='#89312f'
            self.name.focus()
            return
        name1 = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        Entry(frame, textvariable = StringVar(frame, value=name1)).grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

class UpperEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self._var = kwargs.get("textvariable") or StringVar(parent)
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(textvariable=self._var)
        self._to_upper()

    def config(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        self.configue(cnf, **kwargs)

    def configure(self, cnf=None, **kwargs):
        var = kwargs.get("textvariable")
        if var is not None:
            var.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = var
        super().config(cnf, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, item):
        if key == "textvariable":
            item.trace_add('write', self._to_upper)
            self._var = item
        super.__setitem__(key, item)

    def _to_upper(self, *args):
        self._var.set(self._var.get().upper())

class CurrencyEntry(Frame):
    def __init__(
            self, parent, *args,
            currency_symbol="€", thousand_sep=".", decimal_sep=",", **kwargs
            ):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(
            highlightbackground="#000000", highlightcolor="#000000",
            highlightthickness=1, relief=FLAT
            )
        self._int_var = StringVar(self)
        self._dec_var = StringVar(self)
        vcmd_int = (self.register(self.on_validate_int), '%S')
        vcmd_dec = (self.register(self.on_validate_dec), '%S')
        self._thousand_sep = thousand_sep
        self._decimal_sep = decimal_sep
        self._int_entry = Entry(
            self, textvariable=self._int_var,
            validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd_int,
            borderwidth=0, relief=FLAT, justify='right',
            width=15, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._int_entry.pack(side="left", fill="x")

        self._dec_label = Label(
            self, text=decimal_sep, relief=FLAT, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._dec_entry = Entry(
            self, textvariable=self._dec_var,
            validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd_dec,
            borderwidth=0, relief=FLAT, width=2,
            highlightthickness=0
        )

        self._sym_label = Label(
            self, text=currency_symbol, relief=FLAT, highlightthickness=0
            )
        self._sym_label.pack(side="left")

        self._int_last_index = True
        self._dec_first_index = False
        self._int_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._on_int_release)
        self._dec_entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self._on_dec_release)

    def on_validate_int(self, char):
        if char not in "0123456789" and char != self._decimal_sep:
            return False
        return True

    def on_validate_dec(self, char):
        if char not in "0123456789":
            return False
        return True

    def _on_int_release(self, event):
        if self._int_entry.index(INSERT) == self._int_entry.index(END):
            if self._int_last_index and event.keysym == "Right":
                self._last_index = False
                self._dec_entry.focus_set()
            else:
                self._int_last_index = True
        else:
            self._int_last_index = False

        text = self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, "")
        if self._decimal_sep in text:
            int_, dec = text.split(self._decimal_sep)
            self._int_var.set(int_)
            self._sym_label.pack_forget()
            self._dec_label.pack(side="left")
            self._dec_entry.pack(side="left")
            self._sym_label.pack(side="left")
            self._dec_var.set(dec[:2])
            self._dec_entry.focus_set()
        self.set_thousand_sep()

    def _on_dec_release(self, event):
        key = event.keysym
        if key == "Left" and self._dec_entry.index(INSERT) == 0:
            if self._dec_first_index:
                self._dec_first_index = False
                self._int_entry.focus_set()
            else:
                self._dec_first_index = True

        elif key == "BackSpace" and self._dec_entry.index(INSERT) == 0:
            if self._dec_first_index:
                self._dec_label.pack_forget()
                if self._dec_var.get() and int(self._dec_var.get()):
                    self._int_var.set(
                        self._int_var.get() + self._dec_var.get()
                        )
                    self._dec_var.set("")
                self._dec_entry.pack_forget()
                self.set_thousand_sep()
                self._int_entry.focus_set()
                self._last_index = True
            self._dec_first_index = True
        else:
            self._dec_first_index = False

    def set_thousand_sep(self):
        if not (text:= self._int_var.get()):
            return
        sep = self._thousand_sep
        new_text = (f'{int(text.replace(self._thousand_sep, "")):,}'
                        .replace(",", self._thousand_sep)
                         )
        self._int_var.set(new_text)
        if (dif:= new_text.count(sep) - text.count(sep)) > 0:
            self._int_entry.icursor(self._int_entry.index(INSERT) + dif)

    def get(self):
        return (f"{self._int_var.get().replace(self._thousand_sep, '')}" f".{self._dec_var.get()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    aplication = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Que al iniciar la ventana, el focus de mi treeview quede seleccionando la primera fila de los registros, sin que tenga que darle clic a la fila para ello.

Simplemente tienes que usar los métodos `ttk.TreView.selection_set` y `ttk.TreView.focus` una vez que tengas los datos cargados en el `TreeView`.

```
def __init__(self, window):

    # Resto del código

    self.get_products()  # Después de ésto
    item = self.tree.identify_row(0)
    self.tree.selection_set(item)
    self.tree.focus(item)
```

### Que al seleccionar cualquier fila, estos datos se monten en los campos respectivos del formulario de arriba, para luego proceder a actualizarlos.

Simplemente usa el evento `TreeviewSelect` del `TreeView` y enlazarlo a una callback que haga el trabajo:

```
def __init__(self, window):

    # Resto del código

    self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self._on_tree_select)  # <<<<<<<<<

    self.get_products()
    item = self.tree.identify_row(0)
    self.tree.selection_set(item)
    self.tree.focus(item)

def _on_tree_select(self, event):
    current_item = self.tree.focus()
    if not current_item:
        return
    data = self.tree.item(current_item)
    nombre = data["text"]
    precio, stock, seccion = data["values"]
    self.name.delete('0', 'end')
    self.name.insert(0, nombre)
    self.price.set(precio)
    self.stock.delete('0', 'end')
    self.stock.insert(0, stock)
    self.section.delete('0', 'end')
    self.section.insert(0, seccion)
```

Hay que modificar la clase `CurrencyEntry` ya que ahora mismo no proporciona ningun método para signar valores:

```
class CurrencyEntry(Frame):

    # Resto del código       

    def set(self, value=""):
        if value:
            text = value.replace(".", self._decimal_sep)
            if self._decimal_sep in text:
                int_, dec = text.split(self._decimal_sep)
                self._int_var.set(int_)
                self._sym_label.pack_forget()
                self._dec_label.pack(side="left")
                self._dec_entry.pack(side="left")
                self._sym_label.pack(side="left")
                self._dec_var.set(dec[:2])
            self._int_var.set(int_)
            self.set_thousand_sep()
        else:
            self._int_var.set("")
            self._dec_var.set("")
            self._dec_entry.pack_forget()
            self._dec_label.pack_forget()
```

### Un error en la linea 124 después de agregar campos en la tabla y limpiar campos.

`CurrencyEntry` no deriva de `Entry` y no implementa el método `delete`. O lo implementas o simplemente, tal como está la clase `CurrencyEntry` (con la modificación de arriba), cambia la linea:

```
self.name.delete(0, END)
```

por

```
self.name.set("")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como siempre gracias amigo, voy a aplicar y mas tarde le comento. Bendiciones.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya monte esas lineas y funciona, gracias, pero noto que automáticamente se me están llenando los campos de arriba al navegar por cada registro del treeview, pero  no es eso lo que necesito. Lo que necesito es que los campos se rellenen solo al presionar Enter, hacer  doble clic sobre la fila seleccionada, o hacer clic en el boton Edit que esta debajo del treeview, ya que si lo dejo así, no voy a tener los campos limpios o disponibles para cuando necesite agregar un nuevo producto, en vez de actualizar. Le agradezco mucho su ayuda por favor. Saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo @FJSevilla, perdone. Esta por ahi?